# Using a php function in a while loop to get the values and the counts of the values in same column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform a query inside a while loop that is getting values from a column. I am trying to query first to get all my values from a column in my DB and then get the count of how many times that value is in that column.

**Examples of output trying to get**

myValue is in the column 3 times

myOtherValue is in the column 10 times

myOtherOtherValue is in the column 22 times

**Example of code**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id, columnName FROM tableName"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $id = $row['id'];


         function myCount($id)
          {
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE name = '$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $count = mysql_fetch_array($result);
          }

   echo "$id is in the column $count[0] times";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a function inside the while loop.

Using `COUNT(*)` with a `GROUP BY name` clause, then you could solve the problem with only one query.